# Class 'Anonymous class derived from Callback' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onError(Exception)' in 'Callback'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Class 'Anonymous class derived from Callback' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onError(Exception)' in 'Callback'

I am opening an old project. Now how to solve this problem?

my code is:

```
 Picasso.get().load(p.getImageUrl()).into(iv, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                        Bitmap bitmap = convertImageViewToBitmap(iv);
                        Bitmap hiResBitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 600, 1000);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(hiResBitmap);

                        // iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //   saveImageAndSavePathToSharedPrefrence(bitmap, p.getPost_id());
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: From WebUrl " + " Position :  " + position + " PostId: " + p.getPost_id() + " Url : " + p.getImageUrl());

                        tvPhotoLink.setText("Photo Link");
                        tvPhotoLink.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        tvPhotoLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                go_to_website(p.getImageUrl());
                            }
                        });
                        tvPhotoLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                        Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess:3_0 Picasso Error: from Net  " + " Image Position Url is not Valid: " + "ImageUrl is :  " + p.getImageUrl());

                        tvPhotoLink.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                });
```

I want to run the file and find the solution

Comment: You should either make it abstract (doesn’t seem right) or implement abstract method 'onError(Exception)’ (seems right). This information was contained in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet the wrong signature of `onError()` is used, so the required method is not implemented. Please try replacing the line `public void onError() {` with `public void onError(Exception e) {`

Answer (score 0):

Error message is telling you that your anonymous class derived from Callback must implement the abstract method `onError(Exception)`. In your code, you have implemented `onError()` without an Exception parameter. You need to modify your onError method to take an Exception as a parameter.

```
@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
//...
}
```

see for reference: https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Callback.html